# Facebook.getAuthResponse() seems to be broken

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-actionscript-api

Since early morning (gmt+1) the Facebook.getAuthResponse() command of the facebook-actionscript-sdk seems to be broken. It does not return neither the access_token nor the uid but return "null" instead.

This is very crucial for our facebook app, since we've been using this functionality very commonly.

One problem is our app init() function, but this is of course just one place where the command is used:

```
function handleInit(success:Object, fail:Object):void
{
    if (success && success != null)
    {

        if (Facebook.getAuthResponse().accessToken)
        {

            //
        }
        else
        {
            ExternalInterface.call("redirect", appID,"publish_actions","...");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ExternalInterface.call("redirect", appID,"publish_actions","...");
    }
}
```

Did anyone else encounter the same problem or knows a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be caused by this FB platform bug report:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/405378606190941

Fix will be pushed later today.
Until then, there's a workaround in that bug report.

Comment: Thank you very much Donn! This seems to be exactly the source of our problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this is really unacceptable. Same exact issue from the as3 sdk completely broke our app. You can get the uid from the login callback, that is still giving a working auth response for some reason